# Is it possible to use DOM on an external webpage?

Tags: php, dom

I like to use the list on this page: [list of teams of soccerclub](https://www.voetbalvlaanderen.be/club/1771/ploegen)

But I always get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null in /home/u562375926/domains/lucswebsite.tech/public_html/resp/scrapvv.php:152 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u562375926/domains/lucswebsite.tech/public_html/resp/scrapvv.php on line 152

using this code:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$file = 'https://www.voetbalvlaanderen.be/club/1771/ploegen';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($file);
$club = $html->find('div',8)->find(h2);
echo $club. '<br>';
 
?>
```

I have used the same page in ParseHub and I get all a hrefs and the text of the corresponding spans.

Is it possible that DOM is not working on that page?

Comment: `$html` is NULL use `var_dump` and see what `$html->load_file($file)` gives back.

Comment: By adding `echo var_dump($html). "<br>";` I get a very long list see at [https://lucswebsite.tech/resp/scrapvv.php ]

Comment: Sorry, missed there are 2 `find` calls. So that indicates that `$html` itself is not null so your `div` find must be failing or not finding 8/9 elements (not sure what the second param does there). What does `$html->find('div')` have and what does `$html->find('div', 8)` have? (Personal preference here, I'd use domdocument rather than this non-native library)

Comment: `$html->find('div')` says: array(0) { }  and `$html->find('div,8')` gives: NULL

Comment: There isn't a div on that page. Looks like all content is loaded dynamically via javascript.

Comment: Yes that is what you see in the page source, but with element inspector you see all the tags. Is the inspector not the DOM?

Comment: The inspector shows the DOM with all JS modifications. View page source is the content with no JS/live interaction.

Comment: Tanks, then I do it with ParseHub. ParseHub can do the job and gives me all a hrefs and span text for each team.